# Django: GroupBy: and also show the other columns

Tags: django

In Django, in table with multiple columns i want to get the `symbolName` and its `count`

```
TestModel.objects.values('symbolName').annotate(total=Count('symbolName')).order_by('-id')
```

I have other column `id,col1,col2,,,,,,,,,` in the same table

Now is there a way i can now get the First record for other columns as i am ordering them `desc` order

Is there any function in `annotate` called `First('colname')`

Also if possible include all columns in one shot like `First('*')`

**Edit**

I can add other columns using

```
annotate(col1=F('col1'))
```

But how to add all the columns. any shortcut

```
annotate(F('*'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must use `postgres` database for this solution.

If you are using Django version >=2.0, you can use the `Window function` expression.

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import Window

TestModel.objects.annotate(total=Window(
                           expression=Count('*'),
                           partition_by=[F('symbolName')]).order_by('-id')
```

Otherwise:

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

TestModel.objects.annotate(total=RawSQL("Count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY symbolName)", [])).order_by('-id')
```

Now you can get the first or last or any row with all columns and  `total` column.